# Compiling ANE for MacOS & iOS Error Missing native library implementation

Tags: ios, macos, actionscript-3, air-native-extension

I'm trying to compile an ANE but I getting the error "Missing native library implementation". I spend so many hours trying to solve this but without solution. The ANE es CaptureDevice ANE, github/inspirit.

Here's the files tree on build.tmp:

```
/ios
    libcaptureIOS.a
    library.swf
/osx
    captureOSX.framework
    library.swf
```

Extension.xml:

```
<extension xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.1">
    <id>ru.inspirit.capture</id>
    <versionNumber>1.0</versionNumber>
    <platforms>
        <platform name="MacOS-x86">
            <applicationDeployment>
                <nativeLibrary>captureOSX.framework</nativeLibrary>
                <initializer>captureInitializer</initializer>
                <finalizer>captureFinalizer</finalizer>
            </applicationDeployment>
        </platform>
        <platform name="iPhone-ARM">
            <applicationDeployment>
                <nativeLibrary>libcaptureIOS.a</nativeLibrary>
                <initializer>captureInitializer</initializer>
                <finalizer>captureFinalizer</finalizer>
            </applicationDeployment>
        </platform>
    </platforms>
</extension>
```

Command:
adt -package -target ane ./ane/${ANE_NAME} ./extension.xml -swc ./swc/CaptureInterface.swc -platform MacOS-x86 -C ./build.tmp/osx/ library.swf -platform iPhone-ARM -platformoptions ./native/ios/platform.xml -C ./build.tmp/ios/

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might just be a slight problem with your command:

```
adt -package \
    -target ane ./ane/${ANE_NAME} ./extension.xml \
    -swc ./swc/CaptureInterface.swc \
    -platform MacOS-x86 -C ./build.tmp/osx/ . \
    -platform iPhone-ARM -platformoptions ./native/ios/platform.xml -C ./build.tmp/ios/ .
```

Change the library.swf reference to a "." and make sure you have a "." at the end of the iPhone platform as well. Basically this signifies to include everything in the platform directory.